# size occupied by an array of nil

Tags: ruby

I have an array of nil, say

```
a = [nil,nil,nil]
```

what is the size (in bytes) of array a?

I use ruby 1.9.3p484

I tried ObjectSpace.memsize_of() method, but the output is quite confusing.

```
>> a = [nil,nil,nil]
=> [nil, nil, nil]
>> ObjectSpace.memsize_of(a)
=> 0
>> a = [nil,nil,nil,nil]
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil]
>> ObjectSpace.memsize_of(a)
=> 32
>> a = [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil]
=> [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
>> ObjectSpace.memsize_of(a)
=> 40
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays with size smaller than or equal to [`RARRAY_EMBED_LEN_MAX`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/fdb957925f2f3053a0cd45aecb5cd6d65482a79e/include/ruby/ruby.h#L884) (default is 3) will be embedded to improve performance for small arrays. Basically, an array with 3 items or less [will not be allocated on the heap](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/fdb957925f2f3053a0cd45aecb5cd6d65482a79e/array.c#L476).

This explains the confusing output of your example.

```
require 'objspace'
(1..10).to_a.each { |i| p [nil] * i, ObjectSpace.memsize_of([nil] * i) }
[nil]
0
[nil, nil]
0
[nil, nil, nil]
0
[nil, nil, nil, nil]
32
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
40
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
48
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
56
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
64
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
72
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
80
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Note that `ObjectSpace.memsize_of(array)` will only give you the size of the array object itself excluding its items.